# Как привязать текст к сессии телеграмма?

Tags: python, telethon

У меня есть папка "accounts" в которой находятся сессии телеграмма. Мне надо привязать текст через файл txt к каждой сессии и этот файл txt должен быть отдельный для каждой сессии, у меня это сделано через условия файл message.py, эти условия всегда надо менять (если добавляются новые аккаунты и т.д), а это должно быть автоматизировано, вот как это сделано у меня:

**Файл loader.py**:

```
    acc = os.listdir("accounts")

    with open(text_file2, encoding="utf-8") as file:
            message2 = file.read()
    with open(text_file, encoding="utf-8") as file:
            message = file.read()
    with open(text_file3, encoding="utf-8") as file:
            message3 = file.read()

в этом файле у меня подгружаются файлы текстов, но это всё сделано через условия, а надо сделать автоматизировано
```

**Файл message.py**:

```
async def mess(account: dict, chat: str, delay_before_start: int):
    client: TelegramClient = account["client"]
    phone = account["phone"]
    await sleep(delay_before_start)
    while True:
        try:
            if phone == "+27633529916":
                await client.send_message(chat, message)
            if phone == "+276375173896":
                await client.send_message(chat, message2)
            if phone == "+27736332961":
                await client.send_message(chat, message3)
        except Exception as e:
            logger.critical(f"ошибка аккаунта {phone} при отправке сообщения")
        logger.success(f"аккаунт {phone} отправил сообщение")


в этом файле сообщения отправляются, но тоже как вы видите всё сделано через условия без автоматизации
```

**Файл config.py**:

```
text_file = "message.txt"
text_file2 = "message2.txt"
text_file3 = "message3.txt"
```

Главная суть чтобы не было этих бесконечный условий, если будут добавляться новые аккаунты ,то придётся дополнять условия, а это уже не автоматизация